# IP-Based Virtual Hosts Lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, hosts, virtualization

I have multiple IP's and I would like to route each one to its own directory.

This is what I have so far..

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:81" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX "
}
```

While this works, It only works on port 81 and not the default 80.

When I change the port to 80, lighttpd fails to start up with the following error messege.

```
(network.c.300) can't bind to port: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 80 Address already in use
```

Please help!

Comment: do you have another web server on your machine? sounds like a some other service is using port 80 for something else.

Comment: netstat -an | grep 80  What do you see?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was:

```
server.bind = "127.0.0.1"
```

then

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "IP1:80" {
}

$SERVER["socket"] == "IP2:80" {
}
```